# getimage() returns null and hence nullpointerexception

Tags: android, image

I am getting null pointer exception in this function in my android app. When i run it on the emulator and on my own device, it works fine. But in my friend's phone running on Android 8.1, i encounter the following error

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
 at com.delusions.readdelmsg.model.User.getImage (User.java:69)
```

the function facing this error is :

```
 public  Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
}
```

What's wrong with my code  , i am unable to understand and i can't resolve the issue on my end.

Comment: `byte[] image` is probably null

Comment: please show your Log of `byte[] image`